# tensorflow - how to build operations using tensor names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Let's say in Python 3.6 I create two placeholders in tensorflow and for each I assign a name. However, I use the same variable in python to store each tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tfs = tf.InteractiveSession()

p3 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name='left')
p3 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name='right')
```

How can I now create an operation using the names I assigned instead of the variable names?

```
op1 = left * right
op2 = tf.multiply(left,right)
```

Obviously the first one won't work because python doesn't have a variable called 'left' or 'right', but it seems like in the second case I should be able to reference the names. If not, why would I ever bother to set names on a tensor?

In case it matters, I'm doing this on AWS Sagemaker conda_tensorflow_p36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [get_tensor_by_name](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_tensor_by_name).

```
tensor_left = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("left")
tensor_right = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("right")
op = tf.multiply(tensor_left, tensor_right)
```

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933793/how-to-get-reference-by-name-of-variable-placeholder/38935343#38935343) on getting `tf.placeholder` by name (using `get_tensor_by_name`)

[Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784246/992432) for getting result.

Answer (score 2):

For getting tf.Operation by names, you can use [tf.Graph.get_operation_by_name](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name)

```
op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("left")
op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name("right")
```