# Extract (or Set) input/output TF tensor names information from python API instead of saved_model_cli

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, inference

I trained a simple model with Keras/TF2.5 and saved it as saved model.

```
tf.saved_model.save(my_model,'/path/to/model')
```

If I examine it via

```
saved_model_cli show --dir /path/to/model --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default
```

I get these outputs/names:

```
inputs['conv2d_input'] tensor_info:
  dtype: DT_FLOAT
  shape: (-1, 32, 32, 1)
  name: serving_default_conv2d_input:0
outputs['dense'] tensor_info:
  dtype: DT_FLOAT
  shape: (-1, 2)
  name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
```

The names `serving_default_conv2d_input` and `StatefulPartitionedCall` can actually be used for inference.

I want to extract them using python API. If I query it by loading the model:

```
>>> m=tf.saved_model.load('/path/to/model')
>>> m.signatures['serving_default'].inputs[0].name
'conv2d_input:0'
>>> m.signatures['serving_default'].outputs[0].name
'Identity:0'
```

I get entirely different names.

Questions:

1. How can I extract these names `serving_default_conv2d_input` and `StatefulPartitionedCall` from python API?
2. Alternatively how can I define/fix the names when I call `tf.saved_model.save`?
3. What does `:0` mean?

And side question:

How do you handle deployment TF model to production via SavedModel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input/output tensor names displayed by `saved_model_cli` can be extracted as follows:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import saved_model_utils

saved_model_dir = '/path/to/model'
tag_set = 'serve'
signature_def_key = 'serving_default'

# 1. Load MetaGraphDef with saved_model_utils
meta_graph_def = saved_model_utils.get_meta_graph_def(saved_model_dir, tag_set)

# 2. Get input signature names
input_signatures = list(meta_graph_def.signature_def[signature_def_key].inputs.values())
input_names = [signature.name for signature in input_signatures]
print(input_names)  # ['serving_default_conv2d_input:0']

# 3. Get output signature names
output_signatures = list(meta_graph_def.signature_def[signature_def_key].outputs.values())
output_names = [signature.name for signature in output_signatures]
print(output_names)  # ['StatefulPartitionedCall:0']
```

Regarding the meaning of `:0`, `op_name:0` means "the tensor that is the 0th output of an operation called `op_name`." So you might use `…:1` to get the output of an operation with multiple outputs, but many operations are single-output so you'll always use `…:0` for them (source: [@mrry's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933793/how-to-get-reference-by-name-of-variable-placeholder/38935343#comment65228638_38935343%5Dhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933793/how-to-get-reference-by-name-of-variable-placeholder/38935343#comment65228638_38935343)).

Comment: Wow... I was looking for this saved_model_utils and other tools for several days!

Thanks! It is great! I'll award the bounty once stackoverflow allows it!!!