# Specify output tensor_info.name in Keras SavedModel SignatureDef

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I can find the input and output tensor names using `saved_model_cli show --dir <my model> --all`, which, for a model defined like this

```py
input_spec = tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28), name='inputs')
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(type_spec=input_spec))

...

@tf.function
def serve(*args, **kwargs):
  outputs = model(*args, **kwargs)
  return {'outputs': outputs}

...

model.save(
    save_dir,
    save_format='tf',
    signatures={'prediction_default': serve.get_concrete_function(input_spec)})
```

shows

```
signature_def['prediction_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 28, 28)
        name: prediction_default_inputs:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['outputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 10)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
```

To call the model in C++, I need the input and output `tensor_info.name`s. The input name I can hackily identify since it concatenates the signature name and the input tensor name, but how can I (semi) reliably identiy the output name (`StatefulPartitionedCall:0`)? Better yet, is there a way to set these myself in Python? Unfortunately, I am limited to TF 2.5.0 and the pre-built [C API](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c), so I cannot, for instance, inspect the output of `tensorflow::LoadSavedModel` using the C++ API.

Comment: Please refer previous SO thread discussing similar task and see if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142040/tensorflow-2-0-how-to-change-the-output-signature-while-using-tf-saved-model

Comment: That works (somewhat) for the input tensor name, `prediction_default_inputs`, but does not help in setting the output name, `StatefulPartitionedCall`.

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561245/extract-or-set-input-output-tf-tensor-names-information-from-python-api-instea) shows how to get these values in Python, which doesn't answer the question but is enough for my purposes.

Comment: Did you solve this? @glinka

Comment: No, frustratingly. We manually identify them using `saved_model_cli`.